# Validate user input - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am trying to validate user input. Here's the code:

```
do{
        NSLog(@"Please select from the following options: D/ W/ T/ Q");
        res = scanf("%c", &s1);

        if(res ==0) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid entry.");
        }
    }while (res ==0);
```

I want to improve the above code such that it will not allow the user to input anything (such as a number, a string, or any negative number) but only one single character (to be specific, only one of the option given in the prompt).

The current code doesn't do that.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Comment: @Sameera: Feel free to remove the "Thanks" part when you remove the rest of the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    boolean bValid = true;
    do {
        NSLog(@"Please select from the following options: D/ W/ T/ Q");
        res = scanf("%c", &s1);

        if(res == 'D' || res == 'W' || res == 'T' || res == 'Q'){
            bValid = false;
        }
        else{
            //Error message
        }
    } while (bValid == true);
```

You can use this code.
Just check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Well one option is first to read the keyboard as a string

```
char buffer[128];
fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
```

once you have the line, then check whether it is one of the options, seems only the first letter is significant in your case:

```
switch( toupper( buffer[0] ) )
{
   case 'D': {...} ; // do whatever u need to do
   case 'W': {...} ;
   case 'T': {...} ;
   case 'Q': {...} ;
   default: {...} ;
}
```